# Staging test is getting timeout error on rinkeby network: Chainlink VRF and Keeper Issue

Tags: solidity, events, hardhat, testing, chainlink

I am following Patrick Collins course. At chapter 9, when we do a testnet test on rinkeby. The event is not firing. I am using chainlink Keeper and VRF to run the the code as detailed below.

Console error log

```shell
fulfillRandomWords
        works with live Chainlink Keepers and Chainlink VRF, we get a random winner:
    Error: Timeout of 500000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (D:\coding-learning\solidityjsbypatrick\hardhat-smartcontract-lottery\test\staging\Raffle.staging.test.ts)
```

As you can see, I am getting timeout after 500sec.

---

helper-network file

```js
const networkConfig: networkConfigInfo = {
    4: {
        name: "rinkeby",
        vrfCoordinatorV2: "0x6168499c0cffcacd319c818142124b7a15e857ab",
        raffleEntranceFee: "10000000000000000", // 0.01 ETH
        gasLane: "0xd89b2bf150e3b9e13446986e571fb9cab24b13cea0a43ea20a6049a85cc807cc", //30 gwei
        subscriptionId: 7783,
        callBackGasLimit: "500000", // 500,000 gas
        keepersUpdateInterval: "30", // in seconds
    },
    .........
    ......
}
```

---

chain link VRF screenshot

### [image: 04 07 2022_16 11 09_REC]

Chainlink keeper screenshot
[image]

---

Staging Test file (TypeScript)

```typescript
import { SignerWithAddress } from "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/signers";
import { assert, expect } from "chai";
import { BigNumber } from "ethers";
import { ethers, network } from "hardhat";
import { developmentChains } from "../../helper-hardhat-config";
import { Raffle } from "../../typechain-types";

//run onlu on test/main net
developmentChains.includes(network.name)
    ? describe.skip
    : describe("Raffle Staging Test", function () {
          let player: SignerWithAddress;
          let deployer: SignerWithAddress;
          let raffle: Raffle;
          let raffleEntranceFee: BigNumber;
          beforeEach(async () => {
              const accounts = await ethers.getSigners();
              deployer = accounts[0];
              player = accounts[1];
              raffle = await ethers.getContract("Raffle", deployer); //connecting account[0]/deployer with contract. We can use player account to using .connect(player)
              raffleEntranceFee = await raffle.getEnteranceFee();
          });
          describe("fulfillRandomWords", function () {
              it("works with live Chainlink Keepers and Chainlink VRF, we get a random winner", async () => {
                  //enter the raffle
                  console.log("Setting up test...");
                  const startingTimeStamp = await raffle.getLastTimeStamp();

                  console.log("Setting up Listener...");
                  await new Promise<void>(async (resolve, reject) => {
                      // setup listener before we enter the raffle. Just in case the blockchain moves REALLY fast
                      raffle.once("WinnerPicked", async () => {
                          console.log("WinnerPicked event fired!");
                          try {
                              // get data after the winner is picked and event is fired.
                              const recentWinner = await raffle.getRecentWinner();
                              const raffleState = await raffle.getRaffleState();
                              const endingTimeStamp = await raffle.getLastTimeStamp();
                              const winnerFinalBalance = await deployer.getBalance(); //here account[0]/deployer is the only entrant also. So he is the winner.
                              //start assertation
                              assert.equal(raffleState, 0);
                              assert.equal(recentWinner.toString(), deployer.address);
                              assert(endingTimeStamp > startingTimeStamp);
                              await expect(raffle.getPlayer(0)).to.be.reverted;
                              assert.equal(
                                  winnerFinalBalance.toString(),
                                  winnerStartingBalance.add(raffleEntranceFee).toString()
                              );
                              resolve();
                          } catch (e) {
                              console.log(e);
                              reject(e);
                          }
                      });

                      //Entering the raffle
                      console.log("Entering Raffle...");
                      const tx = await raffle.enterRaffle({ value: raffleEntranceFee });
                      await tx.wait(1);
                      const winnerStartingBalance = await deployer.getBalance(); //here account[0]/deployer is the only entrant also. So he is the winner.
                      // And this code Wont compelte untill our listener (above) has finished listening.
                      console.log("Ok, time to wait...");
                  });
              });
          });
      });
```

---

Raffle.sol file [Smart contract]

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/KeeperCompatible.sol";

error Raffle__SendMoreToEnterRaffle();
error Raffle__RaffleIsNotOpen();
error Raffle__TransferFailed();
error Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded(uint256 currentBalance, uint256 numPlayers, uint256 raffleState);

contract Raffle is VRFConsumerBaseV2, KeeperCompatibleInterface {
   
    enum RaffleState {
        Open,
        Calculating
    }
    
    uint256 private immutable i_enteranceFee;
    address payable[] private s_players;
    address private s_recentWinner;
    uint256 private s_lastTimeStamp;
    uint256 private immutable i_interval;
    RaffleState private s_raffleState;

    
    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface private immutable i_vrfCoordinator;
    bytes32 private immutable i_gasLane;
    uint64 private immutable i_subscriptionId;
    uint16 private constant REQUEST_CONFIRMATION = 3;
    uint32 private immutable i_callbackGasLimit;
    uint32 private constant NUM_WORDS = 1;

  
    event RaffleEnter(address indexed player);
    event RequestRafflewinner(uint256 indexed requestId);
    event WinnerPicked(address indexed winner);

    constructor(
        address vrfCoordinatorV2,
        uint64 subscriptionId,
        uint256 enteranceFee,
        bytes32 gasLane,
        uint32 callbackGasLimit,
        uint256 interval
    ) VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinatorV2) {
        i_vrfCoordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinatorV2);
        i_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
        i_enteranceFee = enteranceFee;
        i_gasLane = gasLane;
        i_callbackGasLimit = callbackGasLimit;
        i_interval = interval;
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.Open;
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
    }

    // To enter into lottery
    function enterRaffle() public payable {
        if (msg.value < i_enteranceFee) {
            revert Raffle__SendMoreToEnterRaffle();
        }
        
        if (s_raffleState != RaffleState.Open) {
            revert Raffle__RaffleIsNotOpen();
        }
        s_players.push(payable(msg.sender));

       
        emit RaffleEnter(msg.sender);
    }

    
    function checkUpkeep(
        bytes memory /* checkData */
    )
        public
        view
        override
        returns (
            bool upkeepNeeded,
            bytes memory /* performData */
        )
    {
        bool isOpen = (RaffleState.Open == s_raffleState);
        bool timePassed = ((block.timestamp - s_lastTimeStamp) > i_interval);
        bool hasPlayers = (s_players.length > 0);
        bool hasBalance = (address(this).balance > 0);
        upkeepNeeded = (isOpen && timePassed && hasPlayers && hasBalance);
        return (upkeepNeeded, "");
    }

    
    function performUpkeep(
        bytes calldata /* performData */
    ) external override {
        (bool upkeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("");

        if (!upkeepNeeded) {
            revert Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded(
                address(this).balance,
                s_players.length,
                uint256(s_raffleState)
            );
        }
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.Calculating;
        uint256 requestId = i_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
            i_gasLane,
            i_subscriptionId,
            REQUEST_CONFIRMATION,
            i_callbackGasLimit,
            NUM_WORDS
        );
        emit RequestRafflewinner(requestId);
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(
        uint256, /*requestId*/
        uint256[] memory randomWords
    ) internal override {
        
        uint256 indexOfWinner = randomWords[0] % s_players.length;
        address payable recentWinner = s_players[indexOfWinner];
        s_recentWinner = recentWinner;
        s_players = new address payable[](0);
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.Open;
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
       
        (bool success, ) = recentWinner.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        if (!success) {
            revert Raffle__TransferFailed();
        }
        emit WinnerPicked(recentWinner);
    }

    //Rest of the getter function..
}
```

---

**Contract address on `rinkeby`**
[0xdc6a50411fb987123bE0D048Cde60c66135e2FDe](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xdc6a50411fb987123bE0D048Cde60c66135e2FDe)

Comment: Sorry I can't comment on this (low rep), but have you solved this issue? I have this same error.

Answer (score 1):

Which Patrick's course are you doing?
He has more than one course, could you add the link, with the time that was your doubt?

I saw your [contract](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xdc6a50411fb987123bE0D048Cde60c66135e2FDe#code), and this address is not registered in your VRF Subscription [#7783](https://vrf.chain.link/rinkeby/7783).

I don't know if this version of the course is using [VRF v2](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf/).

I also saw that the Keepers upkeep [#2025] (https://keepers.chain.link/rinkeby/2025) was canceled.